# Directory.GetAccesControll(); Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms

I'm trying to create a simple Windows Forms Application that allows to lock and unlock a folders access by providing a path from file explorer. I know what I need to do to create this app but this line of code is getting an error:

```
 DirectorySecurity s1 = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
```

The error states, 'Directory' does not contain definition for 'GetAccessControl'

I am using the namespaces:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.IO;
```

Is there anyone who would know how to fix this error from happening or possibly know how to use an alternative to the GetAccessControl(); Method?

I tried using other ways of adding the GetAccessControl(); method into the code, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get an instance of `DirectoryInfo`.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity s1 = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
```

Comment: No problem ;) Also, if necessary, check out exceptions: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.-ctor?view=net-7.0#exceptions)